# Failing to run tests using Nunit ITestEngine

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I am trying to run Nunit tests using ITestEngine, but no tests are being executed.

The test is running when I run via Test Explorer & I see the browser opening,
but now, I wanted to create an option to run from a cmd line.
I created a separate console project and pasted the below code which I found online.
I just changed the dll path to mine.

When I run, console window opens, but no browser opens,
the test is not running and then the only output I see is this:
**Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.**

I don't know what I am doing wrong and how to run the tests from a console project.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string automatedTestsFileName = @"C:\MyProject\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll"; 
                        
            TestPackagepackage = new TestPackage(automatedTestsFileName);
            package.AddSetting("WorkDirectory", Path.GetDirectoryName(automatedTestsFileName));

            using (ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance())
            {
                engine.WorkDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(automatedTestsFileName);
                using (ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package))
                {
                    var result = runner.Run(listener: null, TestFilter.Empty);
                    runner.Unload();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please update the question to tell us what happens. How do you know that no tests are being executed, since you don't do anything with the result?

Comment: Firstly, I must mention it's my 1st time trying to create a test framework in C# in VS, so I might have missed something. The test is running when I run via Test Explorer & I see the browser opening, but now, I wanted to create an option to run from a cmd line. I created a separate console project and pasted the above code which I found online. I just changed the dll path to mine. When I run, console window opens, but no browser opens, the test is not running and then the only output I see is this:  Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: When I debug I see the under 'runner' - 'IsPackageLoaded' = false. i.e the package failed to load...

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect a browser to open. I suggest you try running tests using the NUnit Console runner to see what that looks like. Your own console app could produce similar output but, of course, you have to write the code to produce it. I strongly suspect that your tests are loading and running. The only place in your code where you could expect to see the package loaded is imediately before the unload, because the loading takes place internally when you execute Run. Have you looked at the result variable?